# LibGDX shaperenderer wrong color

Tags: colors, libgdx, shape-rendering

I am in trouble setting the color of my rect. The color of my rect is grey with 0.5f alpha or black with 0. How could I set my color?

This is the code :

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);

shapeRenderer.setColor(67 ,   34 , 167, 0.5f);

shapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, Width, Height);

shapeRenderer.end();
```

Comment: Color values are normalized (between 0 and 1). Assuming you want to specify values between 0 and 255, then divide them by `255f`. (e.g. `setColor(67/255f, 34/255f, 167/255f, .5f)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Xoppa is right

the r, g, b and a in
`shapeRenderer.setColor(r, g, b, a);` are always supposed to be between 0 and 1.

In your case it would be 
`shapeRenderer.setColor(67/255f, 34/255f, 167/255f, 0.5f);`
And don't forget to add the `f` behind the numbers because we need float not double.